# find substring from from array then remove it in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I would like to find if my string contains any element of the array
if it did I would like to remove it
for now I could manage to find if it exist or not but not sure how to remove it
here is a sample of my code

```
const arr = ["hi", "hello"," there"]
const msg = "hi I would like to eat ice";
console.log(arr.some(word => msg.toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase()))); // result true
console.log(msg); // new message should be "I would like to eat ice"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that but you need to take into account the left spaces (like the one after 'hi ').

```js
const arr = ["hi", "hello"," there"];
const msg = "hi I would like to eat ice";
const newMsg = arr.reduce((acc, subStr) => acc.replace(subStr, ''), msg)
console.log(newMsg); // new message is " I would like to eat ice"
```